# Lines with nearly equal lengths and small X-coordinate difference

Tags: python, opencv, line

I want to group lines that are close together, and their x1,y1,x2,y2 coordinates are also close. It might be a bit confusing, so I have simulated my desired result in the image below. I have done well on the horizontal lines, but the vertical lines are having a few errors.[image]

I used a similar approach to horizontal lines, but I only sorted the lines in reverse order and performed the operations in reverse order to match Y. However, the results were not as expected. I might be wrong. Here is my code, the commented part is the part I used for horizontal lines.

```
def connect_close_vertical_lines(Test_line_bg, group, distance_threshold=30):

    sorted_group = sorted(group, key=lambda line: line[1])
    # sorted_group_vertical_avg = []
    # total_x = 0
    # len_x = 0
    # for line in sorted_group:
    #     x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[:4]
    #     total_x += x1
    #     len_x += 1
    # avg_x = total_x / len_x
    # for line in sorted_group:
    #     x1, y1, x2, y2 = line[:4]
    #     x1 = x2 = avg_x
    #     sorted_group_vertical_avg.append((x1, y1, x2, y2))

    connected_line = sorted_group[0]
    for i in range(1, len(sorted_group)):
        line = sorted_group[i]
        x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, connected_line[:4])
        x3, y3, x4, y4 = map(int, line[:4])


        dist_2 = abs(x2 - x3)
        if dist_2<30:
            distance_threshold=distance_threshold*2
        dist = abs(y2 - y3)


        if dist < distance_threshold:
            connected_line = (x1, y1, x1, y4)

        else:
            connected_lines_drawn_vertical.append(connected_line)

            cv2.line(Test_line_bg, (x1, y1), (x1, y2), (255, 255, 255), 3)


            connected_line = line
    connected_lines_drawn_vertical.append(connected_line)

    x1, y1, x2, y2 = map(int, connected_line[:4])
    cv2.line(Test_line_bg, (x1, y1), (x1, y2), (255, 255, 255), 3)
```

And [data here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1neeT5SJ8n80ltwb9eUmWmTtOUVX1K5kZ/view?usp=sharing).
These are my coordinates of point x1,y1,x2,y2. My image size is 2675*2275. I really appreciate your help, thank you everyone

Comment: I'm sorry, The old link is wrong. I have updated them

Comment: Do you mean you want to remove the lines inside the red boundaries? Is that equivalent to removing everything between the two longest lines?

Comment: @MarkSetchell No bro, I want to merge them into 1 group, which is a tuple containing lists, in which the list contains the lines in the area I circled in red. My deeper intention is that I want them to be aligned and have the same length, so I want to group them first and then I calculate the average length and coordinates to make them look better.

Comment: If you have an algorithm that works well for horizontal lines, maybe you could rotate your image 90 degrees and apply it?

Comment: Are there always more of the shorter lines of interest than there are long (uninteresting) lines?